# What is the IEC 60617 schematic symbol for jumper and test point?

Tags: schematics, symbol, standard, production-testing, jumper

What is the IEC 60617 schematic symbol for jumper and test point?

I have tried to find it in the official standards but it seems not to be defined explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

See `IEC 60617 02-03-07` how to combine contacts. A jumper has 2 contacts, just bridge these. 
A test point in form of a pin can be visualized by `IEC 60617 03-03-03`